# How to add form to existing class?

Tags: c++

I have an existing (QCreator build) class derived from QTextEdit

```
 class CCC_MdiChild : public QTextEdit
```

I like to **add GUI form** like so

I have no issue creating new form.ui and adding it to the project.

I do not know how to modify existing constructor ( and its definition )  to include "form.ui" .

**I am asking for an assistance / help to do that.**

Here is my current constructor

Sorry , I did try to format the code but I could not "cut and paste " it as code .
( and I could not reedit it after it was edited once )
Since I did realize my poor formatting any automated comments in that aspect will be ....

Answer (score 0):

The required steps are documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-single-inheritance-approach). For completeness, they are:

- Since you've added the .ui file to the project, the UI compiler should generate the corresponding header ui_form.h, which you should `#include` in the header for your class;
- Add a private member to your class of the type defined in this header, which is in `namespace Ui` and takes its name from your .ui file;
- Call the object's setup function as `setupUi(this)` in the constructor(s) of your class.

Alternatively, you also use [multiple inheritance](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-multiple-inheritance-approach), or avoid including ui headers in header files with the slightly more complicated forward-declared [pointer member](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#using-a-pointer-member-variable) approach.

Comment: My mistake  was - I followed QtCreator to  add new form and that is where all QTCreator assistance stops Thank you for  your  post - it covers both "single" inheritance and multiple  inheritance . Unfortunately at this point my teal problem in not in displaying the process result, hence I cannot really test my new class.